# ¿Alguna manera efectiva de cambiar los meta y tittle de una página ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, seo

Necesito hacer una página ajax rastreable por el robot de Google.

El contenido dinámico es cargado en un div a través de php que hace una consulta a la base de datos. Con la función load de jquery, cargo ese contenido en un determinado div.

Pero al cargar el contenido en el div, la descripción, el title y metas de la página son siempre las mismas, me gustaría poder cambiarlas dinámicamente para que el robot de google no vea siempre la misma página y pueda indexar el contenido cargado dinámicamente como una página independiente.

Por ejemplo me gustaría que se generasen diferentes metas:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://davidwalsh.name/demo/facebook-developers-logo.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://davidwalsh.name/demo/david-facebook-share.png" />
<meta name="description" content="Facebook&#039;s Open Graph protocol allows for web developers to turn their websites into Facebook &quot;graph&quot; objects, allowing a certain level of/>
```

¿Hay alguna forma? ¿alguna idea de cómo podría conseguirlo? Manual, tutorial, etc. Muchas gracias.

Comment: La respuesta rápida es no. Lo ideal es que el contenido que quieres indexar exista como tal en tu sitio web y sea accesible mediante una URL, así tendrás 0 problemas con google y demás buscadores. Luego, de cara al usuario, puedes decidir servir este mismo contenido vía AJAX, por cuestiones de rendimiento, estética o por la razón que quieras. Ni que decir tiene que el contenido debe ser único para cada URL generada y demás reglas de SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo desde jQuery de esta forma:

```
$("title").attr("content", result.myTitle);
```

Este cambiará el que tenga `title` por el valor devuelto del Ajax, ojo tu puedes cambiar `result.img` por una variable si así es el caso.

y `$("meta[name='description']").attr("content", result.myDescription);` para cambiar la description.

Al final el código quedaría algo así:

```
 $.ajax({
    url:"myPage.php",  
    success:function(data) {
      $("meta[name='description']").attr("content", result.myDescription); 
      $("title").attr("content", result.myTitle);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Con este método se cambian los valores del title y meta, pero Google no podrá rastrear el contenido.

Comment: @gontrollez pero para eso, el debe tener seteado en su server estas rutas, hice mal en omitir eso.

Comment: si, eso he intentado expresar en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando Google indexa documentos, los tiene que asociar a una URL. Si quieres cambiar el contenido de una página mediante Javascript y que Google lo considere una nueva página y que tenga su propio indice, tienes que asignarle una URL distinta.

La idea clave de todo esto es que cuando el usuario navega por la web, el contenido se renderiza sin recargar la página (probablemente accediendo al servidor para obtene datos en `JSON` y renderizandose el contenido mediante templates `JS`). Y además, la URL debe cambiarse mediante Javascript. Pero si el usuario recarga la página o accede directamente a la URL, como en el caso de Google, debe mostrarse directamente el contenido asociado a dicha URL.

A no ser que tengas mucho dominio y ganas de trabajar repetitivamente, para ello tienes que usar algún framework MVC como Angular, Ember, React + [flux|redux|...] etc.

No creo que tengas ningún tutorial o recurso de calidad en español acerca de estos temas. En inglés tienes que buscar tutoriales por las palabras clave `SPA`, `crawlable`.

**En resumen**: si no conoces ninguno, aprende a usar algún framework MVC Javascript, que te permite realizar lo que quieres.

Aqui tienes una pregunta en SO en ingles:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530258/how-to-make-a-spa-seo-crawlable